# Shapley-Shubik Power with no quota (weighted voting)

Tags: voting-theory

[image]

I'm learning weighted voting methods and MathLab does a terrible job explaining this question so I'm trying to get clarification.

I don't understand how you can find a critical player without a quota. Normally these types of questions are asked like so [4:3,2,1] where 4 is the quota and 3,2,1 are P1, P2, P3 but no vlaues are given so how can you determine which is the critical player? (noted with underlines)

Comment: Knowing the only winning coalitions tells you exactly when a sequential coalition becomes a winning coalition. For instance, knowing $\{ P_1, P_2\}$, $\{P_1, P_3\}$, $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ are the only winning coalitions tells you that, in the sequential coalition $\langle P_3, P_2, P_1 \rangle$, which player *must* be the pivotal player?

Answer (score 1):

You read each sequential coalition from left to right, and you stop when it becomes a winning coalition. The odd thing about this problem is that it's using the same notation $\langle \rangle$ to refer to unordered winning coalitions, and ordered sequential coalitions - I'd prefer to just refer to an unordered coalition using set notation, e.g., $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$.

To step through an example of $\langle P_3,P_2,P_1 \rangle$:

First you have a coalition $\langle P_3\rangle$ by itself. This isn't a winning coalition yet, so we add the next member. Now we have $\langle P_3, P_2 \rangle$. This still isn't a winning coalition. Finally, we go to $\langle P_3, P_2, P_1 \rangle$. This matches one of the winning coalitions (up to ordering), so the last member added - $P_1$ - is the pivotal member.

As an aside, pivotal and critical are two different things - pivotal is looking at a coalition with an order (e.g., Shapley-Shubik), critical is looking at an unordered coalition (e.g., Banzhaf).